# What will be the equivalent JPA CriteriaBuilder for following query?

Tags: spring, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

What will be JPA2 criteriaBuilder query for following?

```
Select * from Transaction t1 
where t1.version = (
    select max(t2.version)
    from Transaction t2
    where t1.id=t2.id
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
CriteriaQuery<Transaction> query = cb.createQuery(Transaction.class);
Root<Transaction> t1 = query.from(Transaction.class);

Subquery<Integer> maxVersion = query.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<Transaction> t2 = maxVersion.from(Transaction.class);
maxVersion.where(cb.eq(t1.get(Transaction_.id), t2.get(Transaction_.id));
maxVersion.select(cb.max(t2.get(Transaction_.version));

query.where(cb.eq(t1.get(Transaction_.version), maxVersion));
query.select(t1);
```